# Where should I stay in Lisbon?

Tags: accommodation, recommendations, lisbon

We are going to Lisbon in April and I have been doing research on where to stay there. The books I have been reading say that Bairro Alto is fun but loud. We like fun but to a certain extent (we don't stay out till the wee hours, we like sleeping well :) ).

Near Rossio or Chiado seems like a good choice. Is it?

Also we may consider staying near the Parque Eduardo VII, but it doesn't look like a short walk to Rossio, Baixa, Chiado and Bairro Alto from there. How late does the subway stay open?

We like having nice places nearby to go to in the evening if we feel like it, like a restaurant or a bar. We don't want to stay in a neighbourhood that is totally "dead" after a certain hour. Can someone please give us a bit of advice?

Comment: Where you should stay is entirely up to you and your preferences. But keep in mind that Lisbon is a small city, and during the day you can get anywhere by metro in about 30 minutes or less, and after 1am, you can still get back home on the night bus (usually every hour, depending on where you are), and even taxis are affordable. That doesn't mean you should try to stay far from down town--it's just to point out that practically anywhere is still within a reasonable distance of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rossio / Chiado area are both very good options. And so is near Parque Eduardo VII though I have some comments here:
If it's near the Rotund (Marquês), it's practicaly downtown,  it's perfectly walkable. It's no longer than 10 min for Bairro Alto. You have the begining of Avenida da Liberdade right there and right after starts Rossio. You can find many (good) restaurants along the way. This is a very important and beautiful Avenue.

If it's in the upper part of PE VII, than you can add an extra 10 min to arrive to Bairro Alto or anywhere else downtown. It's, of course, walkable as well, but a bit more. It depends on your likes/dislikes.

Regarding subway: depending on where you stay near PEXVII you have several choices for the station: Marques, Parque or S. Sebastiao. Subway closes around 1AM.

Comment: Can the person that downvoted tell what's wrong? if he/she disagrees just add a comment and I'll improve the answer.